flutter on mac using VScode - instll cocoapods errorr
i have this errors, i tried so hard to fix but not lucky..
1- i want to install cocoa-pods for my flutter on mac  iPhone project
2- but the system tell me must instal ruby , but i faced issues when i trying to instal ruby
note: my English language is very poor , so please just give me the steps step by step i mean the command..
(base) Nonia@Saeeds-MacBook-Pro home_wid %  sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods

Password:
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6. Try installing it with `gem install drb -v 2.0.6` and then running the current command again
        drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
(base) Nonia@Saeeds-MacBook-Pro home_wid % gem install drb -v 2.0.6
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.



Try the following steps:

Install drb version 2.0.6:
gem install drb -v 2.0.6


Then, install CocoaPods:
sudo gem install cocoapods



